# How to get newsletter subscribers email id in transactional email templates in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

I want to access newsletter subscribers email id in transactional email templates, how to access that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer,

just use `{{var subscriber.getSubscriberEmail()}}` in your email template.

you will get subscribers email id.